# Make scroll-bar appear on hover of scroll-bar-track

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the custom scroll-bar styles via CSS to implement custom scroll-bars in webkit. If other browsers have implemented prefixed or the unprefixed versions/version please let me know.

But, on to my question. Is there a way I can make the scroll-bar appear on hover of the scroll-bar-track?

Kind of like in Mac OS X Lion and Mountain Lion ?

Here is my CSS for the custom scroll-bars"

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jquery solution, since you mentioned it that you need it to show when you hover on it.
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HnHCb/1/)

```
var bodywidth = $('body').width();
var scrollwidth = 10;
$('body').mousemove(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;

    if(x>bodywidth-scrollwidth)
        $('body').addClass("auto");
    else
        $('body').removeClass("auto");
});

body
{
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.auto
{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make the scroll-bar appear more gracefully like a fade-in?

Comment: Could you do, that I just viewed it and it is still a jerky transition / not fading in.

Comment: Sorry, i'm trying at the moment, but for now its not working.

Comment: Maybe add the class, hide the class, then fade it in?

Comment: i tried all of that, and it applies to the body, so fade in or out will apply to the body instead, which i believe is undesirable. im trying to manipulate `-webkit` classes, but no success, i also tried with css3 transitions, but it seems that they dont work on scrollbars

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: THIS ANSWER IS NO LONGER VALID WITH CURRENT BROWSERS**

It's a simple matter of using the `overflow-y` property and showing it with the `body:hover` pseudo class. I also added some padding that would hide on hover so the text wouldn't change place when the scrollbar appears as the padding when the scrollbar is hidden takes up that space.
Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/J4gc9/1 
CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
body{
    overflow-y:hidden;
    padding-right:12px;
}
body:hover{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    padding-right:0px;
}
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work anymore in either Firefox, Chrome or Edge. The scrollbar gets confused and flips into a state of hidden, shown, hidden, shown when moving over the scrollbar location.

Comment: @FrankHale You are correct. I have updated my answer accordingly. Good thing I wasn't marked  answer :P